# How do I use custom Javascript in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Coming from React, i am really confused. In `pages/index.js`, suppose I have a button with `onClick` listener, and clicking on that button will log "you clicked" in the `console`. How do i implement this? I want that page to be statically generated and also give that button some functionality.

The reason I am having a lot of trouble is because in React tutorials or even in my projects, if i needed some functionality i'd do this:

```
function handleClick() {
  document.body.style.background = "black" 
  console.log("you clicked") //nothing is logged in console
}

export default function App() {
  return(
    <button onClick{() => handleClick}>Click Me</button>
  )
}
```

I was gonna use this Next.js to see how `state` works. But I encountered a different problem. Unless I use `inline function` in `onClick`, it doesnt work. If I use a seperate `handleClick` function, the DOM doens't even show that I had an `onclick` event. I learned that's because Nextjs is rendered server side, so it doesnt have access to DOM and console etc. Then how do i do this?

I just transitioned from React, and in every tutorial, those guys would use `handleClick` func or whatever to handle events and stuff. But I couldnt find a solution to do this in Next, how does everyone handle this then? Because pages have interactive buttons right? Are those pages not statically generated then?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot call function `handleClick`:

```
<button onClick{() => handleClick()}></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

the same way you do it in react with your onClick function

Comment: it works if i put inline function. but if i use a seperate handleClick function or something, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Static generation pre-rendering does not change the interactivity of any page, check the following from Next.js documentation :

> Each generated HTML is associated with minimal JavaScript code
> necessary for that page. When a page is loaded by the browser, its
> JavaScript code runs and makes the page fully interactive. (This
> process is called hydration.)

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages

Comment: No need for an inline function to work, please check https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-feather-0icp6?file=/pages/index.js